# Freeform Pro Dynamic Admin Notifications

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms, variable

Is it possible to use a form field as a variable address to send admin notifications to different addresses?

The scenario is that the notification needs to be sent to a different address dependent on some element in the form.

Comment: Please clarify: is the recipient arbitrary... based on user input text or is it selected from a predefined set?

Comment: @AllInOne it will be from a pre-defined set

Comment: @AllInOne it's also worth noting that it could be to one or many addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with FreeForm Pro to create variable 'recipients' on the fly inside the template tag:

```
{exp:freeform:form ... recipients="yes" recipients_limit="1"
  recipient1="recipient1-key|recipient1@email.com"
  recipient2="recipient2-key|recipient1@email.com"
  recipient_template="admin_contact"}
```

Then you could do something like:

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="recipient_email" value="{freeform:recipient_value1}">
  Recipient One
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="recipient_email" value="{freeform:recipient_value2}">
  Recipient Two
</label>
```

This hides the address from the client but makes the form extremely flexible. Simply disable the Admin Notifier in the form settings, and you're sorted. The `recipient_template=""` parameter defines the email template used to send the email.

With some smarts, you can even create a dynamic template to send different details to the different recipients! Brilliant :)

Comment: Is there any way to do this without having the user select anything? We have a modal that pops up based on which person is selected and want the form to be emailed to that person. So looking to set the selected recipient automatically based on which person the user clicks on. Thoughts?

Comment: That sounds like a very specific UI flow. Without seeing what you're trying to achieve, I'd make a ton of assumptions, but it could still be possible. Essentially the user *is* selecting something, just not in a traditional form control sense... you just need to find a way to map that selection to one that interfaces well with the Freeform functionality. You may be able to achieve the desired effect with some Javascript and a hidden input field instead of radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You'll definatly need to develop an extension which hooks freeform. Sounds complicated but its real easy, I've done it many times with freeform (you'll be suprised what clieents ask for) and you'll only be writing the smallest of extensions really..

Creating extensions is documented here ; https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html, and the freeform hook itself is documented here ; http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/extension_hooks/#freeform_module_admin_notification.

You'll be looking to hook on `freeform_module_admin_notification` so as not to interfere with user destined emails.

Essentually when your done, you'll have an extension that fires a function whenever an admin notification is going to be sent, you'll get a `$vars` array with all the message details and such in it, and a `$fields` variable with the postedd fields in it.

I'de recommend setting up your email choices as a bone fide freeform field (for example `notify_choice`), you don't have to include it in the email messsage template but this will ensure the users choice is available via the `$fields` variable. Then much like the example on the freeform docs :

```
public function freeform_module_user_notification($fields, $e_id, $vars, $f_id, $obj)
{

    //have other extensions already manipulated?
    if (ee()->extensions->last_call !== FALSE) {
        $vars = ee()->extensions->last_call;
    }

    //these are the admin emails and the corrisponding form values
    $adminEmails = array(
        0 => 'admin1@site.com',
        1 => 'admin2@site.com',
        2 => 'admin3@site.com'
    );

    //what recipients did the user choose?
    $choices = $fields['notify_choice'];

    //here we process the choices perhaps like this AS EXAMPLE
    $recipientEmails = array();
    foreach ( $choice in $choices ) { 
        if ( in_array ( $choice, array_keys( $adminEmails ) ) { 
            $recipientEmails[] = $adminEmails[$choice];
        } 
    }

    //reset the recipients for the admin email
    $vars['recipients'] = $recipientEmails;

    //required
    return $vars;
}
```

Comment: You should be fine, just be sure to follow the extension guide properly, I've had issues making extensions before with the install ect, but you're not doing anything crazy like adding tables or hooking core functions (not that crazy) so you should be good. Ping a reply if you get stuck or let us know (and tick for the answer :D ) if it's a great success :)

Comment: How did you get on Simon? Did you get there?? If this (or any other) question helped or you have any more to comment then upvote, comment and/or mark the answer, it will help others with similar problems and help the site too! Plus I'd like to know how you faired :D

Comment: I tried this method, but found it to be quite cumbersome and difficult to maintain. I found a built-in method within Freeform that actually handles this scenario pretty well. I'll describe my solution in a separate answer.